# Automate the removal of part of a cells text with Openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, database, loops, openpyxl

I have a list of Instagram URLS on an excel sheet. I want to extract just the username from this list.

For example the existing cell value is:

```
['https://www.instagram.com/thestackoverflow/?hl=en']
```

And from that, I'd like to have `thestackoverflow` in the adjacent cell.

The first part of the problem is removing `https://www.instagram.com/` which should be simple enough, although I cant find out how after hours of straining the documentation. T

The more complex task would be removing the `/?hl=en` (if the link has one) as there are different variables it could be.

However, once the first part is figured out, I think this wouldn't be too much of an issue.

From research I found that [Instagram supports 25 languages](https://about.instagram.com/blog/announcements/instagram-translations-for-25-languages). These will hopefully be using the same host language parameters as Google [which are listed here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results_appendices#interfaceLanguages).

I should be able to make a loop to check if there is a language modifier at the end and remove it.

If anyone could help I'd much appreciate it!

**Update:**

I tried using `urllib.parse` but this didn't work. It doesn't split up the URL in any way. Here is an example of the result:

`ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path="['https://www.instagram.com/thestackoverflow/']", params='', query='', fragment='')`

Comment: Use urllib.urlpase https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

Comment: This didn't work, see my update for result

Comment: If it didn't work, you didn't use it correctly. But seeing as you didn't provide your code, we can't help you. Instead you posted the same question again. That's not a good way to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most straight forward ways of doing this is going to be using .split()

So in your case you could just use:

```
the_url.split('\')[3]
```